# Django - wrap each form element in a <div>

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

The Django forms API has methods `Form.as_p()`, `Form.as_table()` and `Form.as_ul()`, which wrap form elements in `<p>`, `<tr>` and `<li>` tags respectively.

Is there any way to wrap form elements in a `<div>`, like in the canonical [Bootstrap forms example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not [render form fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)?

With this ability you have absolute freedom of how you can manipulate the "look" of a form. You can define CSS `class`es, `id`s etc.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed that part of the documentation.

Comment: Glad I could help. Best regards!